# Is it possible to get the SDE version of layers currently used in a MXD

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, mxd

Is it possible to get the SDE version of layers currently used in a MXD through python?

I can get a list (using arcpy.ListVersions) of all versions in the SDE connection file but I only want the version used in the current mxd. I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.1

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(CURRENT)

database = "Database Connections/SDECONNECTION.sde"
versions = arcpy.ListVersions(database)

#Print the versions available to the user
for version in versions:
    print(version)
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, check the `serviceProperties` properties of the layer [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Layer/00s300000008000000/). Layer example 3 at the bottom of the page gives you a concrete example.

Comment: Connections have a default version, and layers have connections.

Answer (score 1):

Some `arcpy.mapping.Layer` objects have a read only property `serviceProperties` that can be used to check this sort of thing. Two types of layers, ArcSDE and web services, support service properties. `serviceProperties` is a dictionary that has different key value pairs depending on the layer type.The dictionary of service properties for ArcSDE layers (which is the layer type you are referring to) has a key `Version` that you can use to return the version of the geodatabase you are connecting to. However you first need to check if the layer supports `serviceProperties`, and then you can directly check for certain keys. To directly check for the Version you would do this:

```
if layer.supports('SERVICEPROPERTIES'):
    if 'Version' in layer.serviceProperties.keys():
        version = layer.serviceProperties['Version']
```

To do this for every layer in a map document the code snippet would look something like this:

```
mxd_path = r'C:\path_to_data\your_map.mxd'
map_document = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
for data_frame in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(map_document, '*'):
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map_document, data_frame = data_frame)
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.supports('SERVICEPROPERTIES'):
            if 'Version' in layer.serviceProperties.keys():
                version = layer.serviceProperties['Version']
                #do something with version info
```

[See here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) for more details about the service properties dictionary, scroll down to the *Properties* section of the page.